# Implementing an automatic power switch between two batteries based on voltage threshold

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, esp32

I have two batteries. One is currently being used in an RC car, while the other is on standby, charging.

I want to implement a system where, once the voltage of the battery in use drops below a certain threshold, the power source switches to the fully charged battery.
Simultaneously, the depleted battery should start recharging. How can I achieve this?

I am also using a ESP32 in my project. The battery is rated at 12 V. I am using a 4-12 V dynamo as power input for charging.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sort of a vague question because there are many ways to approach this. Two ideas that come to my mind are either voltage comparator or an ADC.

Comment: There are special integrated circuits that do the power path switch based on input voltages. Switching the charging circuit will be more challenging.

Comment: "Simultaneously, the depleted battery should start recharging." using what source of power? The good battery? You will lose a lot of energy that way.

Comment: What drives the ``4-12 V dynamo`` used as the power input for charging?